# How to perform table/row locks in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, locking

In production environments where Django is running on Apache or with multiple Gunicorn workers, it runs the risk of concurrency issues.

As such, I was pretty surprised to find that Django's ORM doesn't explicitly support table/row locking. It supports transactions very handedly, but that only solves half of the concurrency problem.

With a MySQL backend, what is the correct way to perform locking in Django? Or is there something else at play in Django's framework that makes them unnecessary?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Django does not explicitly provide an API to perform table locking. In my experience, well-designed code rarely needs to lock a whole table, and most concurrency issues can be solved with row-level locking. It's an last-ditch effort: it doesn't solve concurrency, it simply kills any attempt at concurrency.

If you really need table-level locking, you can use a cursor and execute raw SQL statements:

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("LOCK TABLES %s READ", [tablename])
    try:
        ...
    finally:
        cursor.execute("UNLOCK TABLES;")
```

Comment: Thanks! My apologies, I actually didn't realize I kept saying "table locks", I more meant locks in general such as row locks. Row locks actually are what I'm looking for in this specific case because as you mentioned, table locks are very expensive.

Comment: @LukeSapan In that case you should read up on isolation levels. In most isolation levels, a write statement in a transaction automatically acquires a `WRITE` lock until the end of the transaction.

Comment: What about for a situation where you SELECT first and then perform one or more writes based on the selected row?

Comment: @LukeSapan You can quite often rewrite those statements to start with a write query. If not, you can use [`select_for_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update).

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @knbk : Can you help me, please? I have written a transaction/locking in views.py and view is redirecting to vendor site for the payment that means lockings are released as the view functionality is over but actually the user is still in merchant page filling up the details. How can i extend the locking between the multiple views?

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the transaction isolation level to serializable, and using a MySQL table type that supports transactions (MyISAM does not, InnoDB does.)

After ensuring you have a backend that supports transactions, you'd then need to disable autocommit (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#autocommit-details) and then ensure that your code issues the appropriate commit or rollback statement at the end of what you consider to be transactions.

There is an example or two in the above referenced docs..

Doing this requires a bit more work and consideration, but provides you with transactions.