# How to take lock on mysql db table for as long as i like through django

Tags: mysql, django

I would like to test issue "**Lock wait timeout exceeded**" that arrises when some part of the code has a lock on db table and other part of code is waiting for the lock to be open.

To reproduce this issue, i need to take lock on db table manually as long as i like. So, is there any way in django to perform this scenario?

This is the issue that i am trying to reproduce:

```
OperationalErrorMySQLdb.connections in defaulterrorhandler
error(1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

Comment: Find which areas of the code are using `LOCK TABLES` and then rewrite them to use transactions so explicit locking it isn't required. Ask for help / guidance if needed.

Comment: The code which is failing because of wait timeout is already in transaction. On failing it rollback the code, which i don't want because it makes the flow of code inconsistent.I have fixed it by applying retry on failing section of code. Now i want to write testcases over it. So i want to manually raise the same Lock wait timeout error in testcae, to check if my fix can handle the error or not. How can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform table/row locks in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693862/how-to-perform-table-row-locks-in-django)